# Javascript: Output error messages are updating on next keystroke (i.e. late) instead on "keydown" or "click"

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, debugging

The functionality for all valid numbers is working fine. When the "keydown" or "click" are used the Roman Numeral conversion properly displays in the outputField. However, when the same is done for one of the error numbers, the outputField updates to show the string after the next keystroke. For numbers greater than 3999 it will also convert the number then display the error string after the next keystroke. Please, proofread through my JS code and let me know any thoughts.

I am still quite new to JS so any other insights in how I can improve my code would be helpful too.

```js
const numberInput = document.getElementById("number");
const convertBtn = document.getElementById("convert-btn");
const outputField = document.getElementById("output-field");
const resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset-btn");
const errorField = document.getElementById("error-field");


//conversion
function toRoman(num) {
  const romanNumerals = {
    M: 1000,
    CM: 900,
    D: 500,
    CD: 400,
    C: 100,
    XC: 90,
    L: 50,
    XL: 40,
    X: 10,
    IX: 9,
    V: 5,
    IV: 4,
    I: 1
  };

  let result = "";

  for (let i in romanNumerals) {
    while (num >= romanNumerals[i]) {
      result += i;
      num -= romanNumerals[i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

//reset
function resetApp() {
  outputField.textContent = "";
  numberInput.value = "";
  errorField.textContent = "";
}

//check user input
function inputCheck() {
  const errorNum = parseInt(numberInput.value)
  if (isNaN(errorNum) || !errorNum) {
    outputField.textContent = "Please enter a valid number";
  } else if (errorNum < 1) {
    outputField.textContent = "Please enter a number greater than or equal to 1";
  } else if (errorNum > 3999) {
    outputField.textContent = "Please enter a number less than or equal to 3999";
  } else {
    outputField.textContent = "";
  };
  return; 
}

//button functionality
convertBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  inputCheck(numberInput.value);
  outputField.textContent = toRoman(numberInput.value);
});

resetBtn.addEventListener("click", resetApp);

numberInput.addEventListener
("keydown", (e) => {
  inputCheck(numberInput.value);
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    outputField.textContent = toRoman(numberInput.value);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>


<body>
<input id='number'>
<button id='convert-btn'>Convert</button>
<p id='output-field'>Output will appear here.</p>
<button id='reset-btn'>Reset</button>
<p id='error-field'>Errors will show here.</p>
</body>
<html>
```

I've tried several fixes with .textContent, .value, .innerHTML, etc. this state is the best working I've had yet. When the outputField.textContent was replaced with errorField.textContent and displaying to a separate paragraph element the error messages worked great. However, that violates the code checks for the class as the error messages must display in the #output element.

Comment: If you have a plain HTML/CSS/JS problem, remember to show the problem off using a runnable snippet, so folks can just hit "run" and see the problem happen.

Answer (score 3):

You have to change the `keydown` event in your EventListener to be `input` when you add an event listener to the `numberInput`:

```js
numberInput.addEventListener
("input", (e) => {
  inputCheck(numberInput.value);
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    outputField.textContent = toRoman(numberInput.value);
  }
});
```

If you also want to be able to track the `Enter` key:

```js
function inputCheck() {
  const errorNum = parseInt(numberInput.value)
  if (isNaN(errorNum) || !errorNum) {
    outputField.textContent = "Please enter a valid number";
    return false;
  } else if (errorNum < 1) {
    outputField.textContent = "Please enter a number greater than or equal to 1";
    return false;
  } else if (errorNum > 3999) {
    outputField.textContent = "Please enter a number less than or equal to 3999";
    return false;
  } else {
    outputField.textContent = "";
    return true;
  };
}
```

```js
numberInput.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  if (inputCheck(numberInput.value)) {
    convertBtn.style.display = 'block';
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
        outputField.textContent = toRoman(numberInput.value);
    } else {
        // pass
    }
  } else {
    convertBtn.style.display = 'none';
  }

});
```

The `keydown` event comes *before* anything is typed in the input box. The `input` event is when something actually is typed in.
Here we add return statements in `inputCheck` to see how the check went, if positive, continue on with calculations, otherwise hide the convert button and disable the option to convert with `Enter`.

Comment: If i do this the "enter" key function is disabled and values over 3999 can still be incorrectly converted by clicking the "convert" button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution. First thing, when you put a `keydown` event it checks the value before you actually type, so you change it to `keyup` which checks after you actually type the character. Also I made the what  `inputCheck()` return true or false, and I put a condition when you press the  Convert button. If it is valid it works but if not, it doesn't put anything.

```js
const numberInput = document.getElementById("number");
const convertBtn = document.getElementById("convert-btn");
const outputField = document.getElementById("output-field");
const resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset-btn");
const errorField = document.getElementById("error-field");


//conversion
function toRoman(num) {
  const romanNumerals = {
    M: 1000,
    CM: 900,
    D: 500,
    CD: 400,
    C: 100,
    XC: 90,
    L: 50,
    XL: 40,
    X: 10,
    IX: 9,
    V: 5,
    IV: 4,
    I: 1
  };

  let result = "";

  for (let i in romanNumerals) {
    while (num >= romanNumerals[i]) {
      result += i;
      num -= romanNumerals[i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

//reset
function resetApp() {
  outputField.textContent = "";
  numberInput.value = "";
  errorField.textContent = "";
}

//check user input
function inputCheck() {
  const errorNum = parseInt(numberInput.value)
  if (isNaN(errorNum) || !errorNum) {
    outputField.textContent = "Please enter a valid number";
    return false;
  } else if (errorNum < 1) {
    outputField.textContent = "Please enter a number greater than or equal to 1";
    return false;
  } else if (errorNum > 3999) {
    outputField.textContent = "Please enter a number less than or equal to 3999";
    return false;
  } else {
    outputField.textContent = "";
  };
  return true; 
}

//button functionality
convertBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (inputCheck(numberInput.value)) outputField.textContent = toRoman(numberInput.value);
});

resetBtn.addEventListener("click", resetApp);

numberInput.addEventListener
("keyup", (e) => {
  
    inputCheck(numberInput.value);
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      outputField.textContent = toRoman(numberInput.value);
    }
  
  
  
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>


<body>
<input id='number'>
<button id='convert-btn'>Convert</button>
<p id='output-field'>Output will appear here.</p>
<button id='reset-btn'>Reset</button>
<p id='error-field'>Errors will show here.</p>
</body>
<html>
```